# How to change date format from yyyy-MM-dd to ddmmyyyy

Tags: c#

I need to autogenerate booking id, example: 02112012/1 ,if its first of 02/11/2012 and accordingly the number after "/" increases, so for that I need to change date format from yyyy-MM-dd to ddmmyyyy so is there any way i can do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy"));
```

yields `02112012`

If you need further customer date formatting, this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) should be helpful =)

Comment: thnks...will try it and let you know
if date is stored in local variable Bdate then??

Comment: Yeah, if you already have a `DateTime` object, just use `myObject.ToString("ddMMyyyy");`

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
// parse the original string value into DateTime.
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("2012-11-02", "yyyy-MM-dd", 
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

// emit to your desired format.
string bookingIdFormattedDate = dt.ToString("ddMMyyyy");

// bookingIdFormattedDate should be "02112012"
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
string dateString = "2012-10-01";
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyy-MM-dd", new DateTimeFormatInfo());
string result=date.ToString("ddmmyyyy");
```